# Cannot render views in template in Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I cannot render my views in templates.
I think I've tried everything.
everything works except data rendering on template.

My model.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from zoo.models import Driver


def MyView(request):
    drivers = Driver.objects.all()
    return render("zoo/base.html", {"drivers": drivers})
```

My template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    {% render_bundle 'app' 'css' %}
  </head>
  <body>
     {{ drivers }}

     {{ drivers.name }}

     {% for driver in drivers %}
         {{driver.name}}

</body>
</html>
```

My database got 315 drivers, contains names and surnames for drivers.

Project structure:

```
Project 
      app
         setting.py
         __init__.py
          ...
      zoo
         templates
              base.html
         __init__.py
         models.py
         views.py
          ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### views.py

In `views.py` change:

```py
return render("zoo/base.html", {"drivers": drivers})
```

to:

```py
return render(request, "zoo/base.html", {"drivers": drivers})
```

#### template

You need to close your `for` loop in your template. There's good information on this worth reading at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/.

```
{% for driver in drivers %}
    {{ driver.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also I'm guessing from the code you provided and your explanation that `{{ drivers.name }}` probably won't render. It won't be until you iterate through your `drivers` QuerySet that you'll be able to access the individual `driver` fields (like `driver.name`).

#### File Structure

It's best practice to namespace your templates and staticfiles. Django's tutorial talks about this at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/. If you do this your directory structure will change from this (what you currently have):

```
Project 
      app
         setting.py
         __init__.py
          ...
      zoo
         templates
              base.html
         __init__.py
         models.py
         views.py
          ...
```

to this:

```
Project 
      app
         setting.py
         __init__.py
          ...
      zoo
         templates
            zoo
               base.html
         __init__.py
         models.py
         views.py
          ...
```

Lastly, I strongly recommend you rename your template to something specific to this particular view. If this is your index view, for example, you could name it `index.html`. Or perhaps `zoo.html` to correspond with the name of your view.

This isn't necessary *but* it will be useful down the road as you build this app out if you want extend a `base.html` file. This is handy because it allows you to cut down on your boilerplate html and just focus on the core functionality of each template/view. It also has the advantage of making it easier to provide a consistent user experience between different pages that all extend the same `base.html` file.

To learn more about this check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/.

***Important Note:*** If you do this, don't forget to change your call to `render` in `views.py` to accomodate your renamed template file.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
return render("zoo/base.html", {"drivers": drivers})
```

Should be this:

```
return render(request, "zoo/base.html", {"drivers": drivers})
```